# Play2 for Scala: is Action Chaining a missing feature?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Few days ago I run into an eventually missing feature of Play, that is Action Chaining. Here's what I mean:

I have a controller with two Actions, and I'd like to call an action from another action in order to stay DRY. My goal is to automatically sign a user in after he signs on.

```
object MyController extends Controller {

   def signOn = Action {
      // ... do stuff to sign the user on
      signIn  // call the next Action
   }


   def signIn = Action {
      // ... do stuff to sign the user in
      Ok("Welcome, Dude!") 
   } 
}
```

I've found this nice but outdated solution here (it's for Play 2.0.x)

http://www.natalinobusa.com/2012/07/chained-actions-in-play-framework-20.html

now I'm trying to write something similar on Play 2.2.x but I'd like to know if it is actually a missing feature and if some of you has already implemented something similar.

And finally: would you think it would be something nice to have in the framework?

Comment: This page from the official docs does not answer your question? http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.2/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: In a way, yes it could solve my needs, but I was looking for a different approach. The solution posted by Johan is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks anyway, I appreciated your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for being nit-picky. :-) But the approach shown in the accepted answer is documented in that page, too (under Composing Actions, second code block).

Comment: Ooops! You're right, I didn't notice it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it like this?

```
def signOn = Action.async { request => 
  // ... do stuff to sign the user on
  signIn(request)  // call the next Action
}

def signIn = Action {
  // ... do stuff to sign the user in
  Ok("Welcome, Dude!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by Johan is what I was looking for. I ended up with this (nice?) solution for a neat chained action controller

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object TestCtrl extends Controller {

  def signOn = Action.async { request => 
  // ... do stuff to sign the user on
    if ( true ) 
      signIn(request)  // call the next Action
    else
      stopChaining( Ok("Stop") )(request)
  }

  def signIn = Action {
    // ... do stuff to sign the user in
    Ok("Welcome, Dude!")
  }

  private def stopChaining(result: SimpleResult) = Action {
    // ... do nothing, just return the result
    result
  }

}
```